# android : How to set Country code manually in emulator

Tags: java, android, country-codes, mobile-country-code

When i use following code , it always shows the country code as US.

```
context = MainActivity.this;
String locale = context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getCountry();

TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
telephonyManager.getSimCountryIso();
```

How can i manually set set country code to IN (india) in emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done the same way as on a real device.
Open the seetings app, got to "Language and Input" -> "Language" and select "English (India)"

Comment: That changes the locale, not the SIM country code (which is sometimes referred to as MCC).

Comment: @zmbq Right, but the OP's `locale` is not from SIM.